# Use Angular Virtual Scrolling with a ui5-table web component having a sticky header

Tags: angular, virtualscroll, ui5-webcomponents

When I use Angular Virtual Scrolling with a ui5-table web component having the sticky-column-header flag set to true the column headers move to the bottom when scrolling down (randomly jumping between).
In my setup I use 100 entries and 3 columns and the virtual scrolling like this:

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="20">
 <ui5-table>
 ..
  <ui5-table-row *cdkVirtualFor="let entry of list">
   <ui5-table-cell>..</ui5-table-cell>
  </ui5-table-row>
 ..
 </ui5-table>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

Top of the table:

[image]

Upper half of the table, here the header column moves randomly up and down:

[image]

At the bottom:

[image]

Someone has any idea how to fix this?